# SDK Manager in Android Studio does not open when clicking SDK Manager icon (V1.0.1)

Tags: android, android-studio

I update Android Studio from V 0.8.14 to V 1.0.1 (build 135.1629389). When I click on SDK Manager icon, a small window saying starting sdk manager it loads then nothing happens. I have set my environmental Variables like this:
JAVA_HOME:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11
JDK_HOME:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11
PATH:C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\android-sdk\sdk\platform-tools\;C:\android-sdk\sdk\tools\

I checked "http://tools.android.com/knownissues" and downloaded the file "find_java.zip" to fix the bug "Can't Run SDK Manager (Broken find_java.bat)" with the same result.

I tried to run SDK manager from a CMD console with the following result:

C:\android-sdk\sdk\tools\lib>"C:\android-sdk\sdk\tools\lib\SDK MANAGER.exe"
Failed to execute tools\android.bat:, error 2
El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado. (it means: The system can not find the specified file)

If I tried to execute directly android.bat from a CMD, I get:

C:\android-sdk\sdk\tools>android.bat
"reg" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, ( it means: "reg" is not a internal or external command)
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Can anybody pleases help me? I am using a 32 bit windows 7 laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem updating from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1. Try this:

https://plus.google.com/107852486976928213243/posts/eASLDXpavAX

```
close android studio
Download http://goo.gl/v0UPm6
goto \sdk
rename 'tools' to 'tools1' (In case you need backup)
extract this zip to \sdk
it will make tools folder in \sdk
restart studio and errors will be gone
```